# Programmatic LUIS Training request has no effect

Tags: c#, http, post, azure-language-understanding, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm using the programmatic Microsoft LUIS API ([see here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f)) for send training request from my frontend to my luis model. My problem is that after sending the POST request the training is planned and never managed so I can't publish my model. Here the api call, I've done also a GET request to see the LUIS status.

```
var requestUrl = $"https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{_appId}/versions/{_appVersion}/train";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _authoringKey);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, null);
response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
return;
```

Why is that? How can I be sure that the training is done? Or how can I force it?

Answer (score 2):

Training is a 2-part operation of request training then check status. Look at [this sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/blob/master/examples/add-utterances/nodejs/add-utterances.js).

Comment: You request training, than poll training to get the status. Do you understand that part?

Comment: yes ok, but haven't I do that? I've made a POST request then a GET one.. What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the contents of the get request. If not all items are marked, keep polling.

Comment: `response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);` this is my get request... I have no utterances to train the model with.

Comment: You can't train until each intent has at least 1 utterance. Look at the app from the LUIS (http://www.luis.com). If you can train it there, you can train it via API. the website uses the API under the covers so F12/debug tools is a good way to see what polling for trained completion looks like.

Comment: Ok thanks. From luis portal I can train my application because I have utterances for the intents, but when I do the get request from my api I do not attach any utterance to train the model with. Is that necessary? I've seen in the debug tool of Chrome that the website make a OPTIONS request (I've tried to do the same with postman but I get a 404 error) then a POST and a GET like I've done. So, I'm wondering if the code I've posted in my question is wrong. Why after a post and a get there is no effect? Thanks

Comment: Your get request should return a JSON response of each model in your app, and its training status. Are you getting this JSON? If yes, what does it look like?

Comment: "[{\"modelId\":\"modelID\",\"details\":{\"statusId\":2,\"status\":\"UpToDate\",\"exampleCount\":69}},{\"modelId\":\"modelID\",\"details\":{\"statusId\":2,\"status\":\"UpToDate\",\"exampleCount\":69}},{\"modelId\":\"modelID\",\"details\":{\"statusId\":2,\"status\":\"UpToDate\",\"exampleCount\":69}},{\"modelId\":\"modelID\",\"details\":{\"statusId\":2,\"status\":\"UpToDate\",\"exampleCount\":69}},{\"modelId\":\"modelID\",\"details\":{\"statusId\":2,\"status\":\"UpToDate\",\"exampleCount\":69}}]"
that's what I get...

Comment: You don't need to do the GETs you see in chrome. You do need to check the returned JSON array to see if all models are trained. If not all are trained, keep polling. If you find your training never finished, log a "General inquiry through user voice" under Support in LUIS.ai